# CSS rotate making links unclickable unless double clicking

Tags: html, css

I can't seem to find the issue that is causing my links to only be clicked on the white portion. It's a "3D" button by that, I mean it is a link with CSS rotate transitions. I'm not able to find any solutions so I'm looking for some help!

Here's the [codepen link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mJErwK).

HTML:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html" data-hover="Home">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="plans.html" class="current" data-hover="Plans">Plans</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" data-hover="Forums">Forums</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="team.html" data-hover="Team">Team</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav {
    background: #e9e9e9;
    margin: -1rem 0rem;
    z-index: 0;
}

nav ul {
    list-style: none;
}

nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    letter-spacing: 0.05rem;
}

nav ul li a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 1rem;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: transform 0.3s ease 0s;
    transform-origin: 50% 0px 0px;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    }

    nav ul li a.current {
    color: #ffc400;
}

nav ul li a: hover {
    background: #e9e9e9;
    color: #000;
    transform: rotateX(90deg) translateY(-22px);
    }

    nav ul li a::before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 4px 0px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% #ffc400;
    color: #FFF;
    content: attr(data-hover);
    transition: #ffc400 0.3s ease 0s;
    transform: rotateX(-90 deg);
    transform -origin: 50% 0px 0px;
}
```

Comment: If you want more clickable area than the text in the <a>, consider adding padding to your <a> or wrapping <li>'s in <a>'s rather than the other way around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the issue is that you're translating the link out of view so it cannot be clicked:

```
nav ul li a:hover {
    background: #e9e9e9;
    color: #000;
    transform: rotateX(90deg) translateY(-22px);
}
```

The dead simple solution to this problem would be simply put an `a` element around the `li` element and change the current `a` element to a `div`, like so:

This way, the `div` and `li` elements that are being translated and rotated are surrounded by the clickable link.

```
<a href="#">
    <li>
        <div data-hover="Forums">Forums</div>
    </li>
</a>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav {
    background: #e9e9e9;
    margin: -1rem 0rem;
    z-index: 0;
}

nav ul {
    list-style: none;
}

nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    letter-spacing: 0.05rem;
}

nav ul li div {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 1rem;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: transform 0.3s ease 0s;
    transform-origin: 50% 0px 0px;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

nav ul li div.current {
    color: #ffc400;
}

nav ul li div:hover {
    background: #e9e9e9;
    color: #000;
    transform: rotateX(90deg) translateY(-22px);
}

nav ul li div::before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 4px 0px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% #ffc400;
    color: #FFF;
    content: attr(data-hover);
    transition: #ffc400 0.3s ease 0s;
    transform: rotateX(-90deg);
    transform-origin: 50% 0px 0px;
}
```

And then adding `a` element styling to make everything work out:

```
nav ul a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Here's the [updated pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oXLzGo).

Comment: Thank's a ton for the help! I really appreciate it.